# When to use iframe, ajax() or load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

**I know iframe and ajax comparisons have been asked many times**. But I would like to add the good jQuery `load()` function, and also ask when to use which one.

I am certain they all have their own specific features, so I don't wanna know which one is faster and so on, I am more eager to recognize **when to use which to retrieve the data from another page**?

```
<iframe>

load();

ajax();
```

Comment: I mostly avoid `<iframe>` it gives security problems, but sometimes there's no option to `iframe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **When to use iframe?**

From **[this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31240)** by **[Manishearth](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/7497/manishearth)**

> Given that framing is deprecated, and `AJAX` has origin control, **`iframes`**
>   is pretty much the only way to embed another page into yours.
>
> GMail is made from `iframes`. The smooth UX of GMail (you can still use
>   it when your internet connection breaks, smooth navigation without
>   having to reload every time) comes from iframes. Again, this could be
>   implemented in AJAX, but it's harder.
>
> On the other hand, issues with iframes (CSRF, clickjacking, etc) are
>   well known to modern developers and they can take measures to avoid
>   that.

<strike>- **When to use Ajax?**</strike>

***Form validation***

> This is almost a no-brainer. It's so much nicer when the form tells
>   you as you are typing if you've filled it out wrong or not. Having to
>   go to the server and then return an error message is not only old,
>   it's slow. Leave the server validation in the form, that's important
>   for accessibility. But for those who can support Ajax, tell them right
>   away.

***Comments***

> Comments on blogs or even just articles are a great use of Ajax.
>   Comments can change all the time, and especially when a commenter hits
>   the comment button, it's nice to see the comment appear immediately on
>   the page.

***Filtering data***

> If you've got a large table with a lot of data in it, a nice
>   application for Ajax is to add filters and sorters to the table.
>   Getting your Web table to act more like Excel is really useful to
>   people.

***Surveys and polls***

> When you click on your vote, the poll would just switch to show you
>   the results. And before you comment, About doesn't yet support Ajax on
>   our polls - but it sure would be nice. Maybe we can give the About.com
>   developers an "Ajax call" of our own.

- **When to use load?**

> As far as `load` is concerned, in my personal opinion, it is used to
>   load documents into any element in DOM, but will have same
>   disadvantages as `ajax` over `iframe` with regard to **cross domain
>   data**. You can use load when the result you are returning is `html`
>   and this provides option to render the result directly to the `DOM`
>   element

---

**UPDATE**:

- **When to use AJAX**

> Basically, the main difference between `ajax` and `load` is that
>   `ajax` has more `options` that can be set before posting data to
>   `server` plus `ajax` can be used to store `data` in the server using
>   `type="POST"` and data returned from the server may be manipulated the
>   way we want unlike load which can be used only to render data.

To conclude - Security wise `ajax/load` is good but as said before if you know the loopholes of security using `iframe` you can take necessary precautions to prevent them too.

**[AJAX USAGES AND DISADVANTAGES](http://voidcanvas.com/should-i-use-ajax-if-yes-when-where-and-why/)**

Comment: Awesome way of explaining `iframe` and `load`, whereas I made a mistake and didn't specify that I meant **retrieving** the data (edited now). Therefore, could you please elaborate on that too when it comes to `ajax`?

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)